# Calculate $d\omega$ of an $n-1$ forms $\omega$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $\omega$ denote the $(n-1)$ form on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ defined by:

$$\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \space f_i \space dx_1\wedge... \wedge dx_{i-1} \wedge dx_{i+1} \wedge ... \wedge \space dx_n$$

where $f_i(x) = \frac{x_i}{|x|^m}$ ($m$ is a fixed positive integer).

Calculate $d\omega$.

I'm only familiar with 1-forms and 2-forms. Can anyone explain to me how (n-1) forms work in the context of this question?

I'm not sure if this is correct but

If: $\omega =\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \space f_i \space dx_1\wedge... \wedge dx_{i-1} \wedge dx_{i+1} \wedge ... \wedge \space dx_n$, then would

$d\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i})\right)dx_1 \wedge dx_{i-1} \wedge dx_{i+1} ...\wedge dx_n$

Where $\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\right) = 0$

because 
$$\frac{\partial \frac{x_i}{|x|^m}}{\partial x_j} = \frac{-2mx_ix_j}{2|x|^{m+2}} = \frac{\partial \frac{x_j}{|x|^m}}{\partial x_i}.$$

Then $d\omega = 0$.

Is this right? Or do I at least have the right idea?

Comment: do you know a good way to get from one forms to two forms?

Comment: No not really..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$d^2 = 0,$ and $d$ obeys a product rule, so we have $$ d\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} df_i\wedge dx_1\wedge\ldots \wedge dx_{i-1}\wedge dx_{i+1}\wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n.$$ We also have $$ df_i = \sum_j \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f_i\right)dx_j.$$ Then use that $\wedge$ is anticommutative and distributive.

Comment: Thank you. You're very kind.

Comment: I posted an answer, is it correct?

Comment: @WannaBeRealAnalysist No. For one, $\omega$ is an $(n-1)$-form so $d\omega$ is an $n$-form. Second, even if your formula were right $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \ne 0.$ $f_i$ and $f_j$ are different functions (as far as I can tell) and these are first derivatives so mixed partial derivatives commuting has no relevance. (But your formula isn't right so really this doesn't need to be explored further.)

Comment: but given the $f$ is defined, wouldn't $\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\right) = 0$? because the partial of $f_i$ with respect to $f_j$ would equal the partial of $f_j$ with respect to $f_i$

Comment: @WannaBeRealAnalysist Yes, actually it does (I didn't seen the explicit form) but it has nothing to do with mixed partials. But it's a moot point I think since that combination does not actually appear in the answer.

Comment: @WannaBeRealAnalysist And again, although the rank of your form is closer to $n$ this time (it is $n-1$ rather than $2$), it needs to be $n$. You need to revisit the whole thing from the ground up I think. They show how to calculate a single term here, along the same lines I sketched in my answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_local_coordinates